# PySpark create combinations using UDF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

This could be a basic question but I have been stuck for sometime now.

I have few columns names and I'm trying to create a list of combinations that combines two elements in Spark. This is the list from which I am trying to create combinations

```
numeric_cols = ["age", "hours-per-week", "fnlwgt"]
```

I am using the `combinations` from the `itertools` module

```
from itertools import combinations
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType

def combinations2(x): return combinations(x,2)
udf_combinations2 = udf(combinations2,ArrayType())
```

But on running the line

```
pairs  = udf_combinations2(numeric_cols)
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sg/Downloads/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 179, in wrapper
    return self(*args)
  File "/Users/sg/Downloads/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 159, in __call__
    return Column(judf.apply(_to_seq(sc, cols, _to_java_column)))
  File "/Users/sg/Downloads/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 66, in _to_seq
    cols = [converter(c) for c in cols]
  File "/Users/sg/Downloads/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 66, in <listcomp>
    cols = [converter(c) for c in cols]
  File "/Users/sg/Downloads/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 54, in _to_java_column
    "function.".format(col, type(col)))
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: ['age', 'hours-per-week', 'fnlwgt'] of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

I am not sure how to use the functions mentioned in the last line for this case. Any directions and hints would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to use an `UDF` for this ? Why not simply run `pairs  = combinations2(numeric_cols)`?

Comment: I guess I have to. I have datasets that have thousands of columns depending on their activity. python `combinations` can take a long amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

First define `udf` properly:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2 ,3)], ("age", "hours-per-week", "fnlwgt"))
```

You can define it with single argument

```py
@udf("array<struct<_1: double, _2: double>>")
def combinations_list(x):
   return combinations(x, 2)
```

or varargs

```py
@udf("array<struct<_1: double, _2: double>>")
def combinations_varargs(*x):
   return combinations(list(x), 2)
```

In both cases **you have** to declare type for the output array. Here we'll use `double` and `structs`.

Make sure that input types match declared output type:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

numeric_cols = [
    col(c).cast("double") for c in ["age", "hours-per-week", "fnlwgt"]
]
```

To call a single argument version use `array`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import array

df.select(
     combinations_list(array(*numeric_cols)).alias("combinations")
).show(truncate=False)
# +---------------------------------+
# |combinations                     |
# +---------------------------------+
# |[[1.0,2.0], [1.0,3.0], [2.0,3.0]]|
# +---------------------------------+
```

To call varargs variant unpack values

```py
df.select(
     combinations_varargs(*numeric_cols).alias("combinations")
).show(truncate=False)
# +---------------------------------+
# |combinations                     |
# +---------------------------------+
# |[[1.0,2.0], [1.0,3.0], [2.0,3.0]]|
# +---------------------------------+
```

Comment: You also do something similar with numpy. Around 6 seconds on my machine for 4000 columns.